# API call working through server side code (node.js, php) but not through JS in browser using fetch()

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am trying to make an API POST request via `fetch()`. When I execute it server side ( PHP or Node.js ) it works properly. When trying to execute it in the browser I get two errors:

1. 405 Error - Method not allowed
2. Access to fetch at 'url' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I have tried adding: mode: "no-cors". I then get the following error:
"401 Unauthorized"
with the following response:

[image: 401 response - https://ibb.co/748rs5S]

Here is my standard js setup:

```
const TrailData = {
      email: "test@test.com",
      first_name: "sample string 5",
      last_name: "sample string 6",
      phone2: "12121212"
    };


    // TRAIL POST ( NOT WORKING )
    fetch('http://webapi.mymarketing.co.il/api/contacts', {
            method: "POST",
            mode: 'no-cors',
            headers: {
              "Authorization": "API CODE //here comes the API CODE",
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(TrailData)
          })
          .then(res => console.log(res) )
          .then(data => console.log(data))
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

My Node js setup is:

```
var postData = {
   
    sms_status: "None",
    email: "test@test.com",
    first_name: "sample string 5",
    last_name: "sample string 6", 
  };

  let axiosConfig = {
headers: {
    "Authorization": "API CODE",
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
}
  };


const Trail = async () =>{
try {
    const response = await axios.post('http://webapi.mymarketing.co.il/api/contacts', postData, axiosConfig)
    console.log(response)
} catch (error) {
    throw new Error(error)
}


  }

 Trail()
```

Node JS works. I get a 200 OK response. The first one doesnt!

Is it possible that the API blocks requests made from the browser?
I have tried so many ways and failed every time using the browser.

Comment: I think you have to run browser with cors disabled or have some local server running that serves those files.

Comment: is that possible to limit APIs this way? , because when trying the same code with another API it works flawlessly....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't send extra headers without CORS (`Authorization` header)

because server does not respond to preflight request you are not allowed to send that request

without CORS you are allowed to send only "Simple requests" see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Simple_requests

see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

for more information

Comment: thank you for your reply! does that mean, it would have to be configed on the API serverside to allow this? and via node.js there is no CORS?

Comment: yes CORS (preflight request handling) need to be configured on the backend (server side) it does not matter what backend is written in anything can handle CORS...

CORS is only browser thing so other platforms (server side, desktop/mobile apps) don't care about it